# How to design two pieces of board in one board and then separate? in ALTIUM

Tags: pcb, altium

I want to make two pieces of PCB on one board and when I get it, I can easily separate it to save money. Do you have any experience?  i use altium designer.

Comment: It’s not difficult however you may not necessarily save as much money as you might think-fast-turn suppliers often ask if there are multiple “designs” on a PCB and adjust prices accordingly.

Comment: How many are you wanting to build? A few, or manufacturing quantities?

Answer (score 0):

Look up pcb panelization as a general topic. Altimum has some resources...

https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/creating-board-fabrication-panel

Answer (score 0):

Make one board but with two halves separated by notches and mouse bites to attach the two halves - see https://www.allpcb.com/mouse_bites_pcb.html.

Note that anytime you have a design like this you should ensure that no reference designators are duplicated or else it could cause issues during assembly. If you're hand-assembling then it doesn't matter.

If you're doing this in production then it's almost always better to create individual PCBAs. There are a few reasons but one of them is that it's difficult to maintain a 1:1 ratio between the Left Board and Right Board because some PCBs may be 'X'd out for failing electrical test. Another reason is that most Contract Manufacturers (CMs) just aren't set up to think like this with their documentation.

Nowadays with low cost PCB fabrication houses (Osh Park, etc.) that charge per square inch it doesn't make as much sense to make family boards consisting of several sub-boards.